How to homogenize this boundary condition?
The domain is $0\le x_i\le l,0\le t\le T,i=1,\cdots,n$. The boundary condition is
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}v\left( \boldsymbol{x},t \right) \mid _{x_i=0}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}v\left( \boldsymbol{x},t \right) \mid _{x_i=l}=\int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x},t \right) \mathrm{d}x_i}
$$
for $i=1,\cdots,n$. How to homogenize it? Another way to say it is if there is a $u(\boldsymbol{x},t)$, satisfying
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}u\left( \boldsymbol{x},t \right) \mid _{x_i=0}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}u\left( \boldsymbol{x},t \right) \mid _{x_i=l}=0,
$$
then what is the relation between $u\left( \boldsymbol{x},t \right)$ and $v\left( \boldsymbol{x},t \right)$ above?

The background
The source of the boundary condition
The initial partial differential equation is
$$
\frac{\partial ^2v}{\partial t^2}-\nabla ^2v=q\left( \boldsymbol{x},t \right) 
$$
with some initial conditions and boundary conditions. And there is a so-called nonlocal condition
$$
\int_0^l{v\left( \boldsymbol{x},t \right) \mathrm{d}x_i}=0.
$$
By integrating the PDE with respect to $x_i$ from $0$ to $l$, and considering the nonlocal condition, one can get the boundary condition (the first formula).

The step is shown below.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^l{\left( \frac{\partial ^2v}{\partial t^2}-\nabla ^2v \right) \mathrm{d}x_i}&=\int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x},t \right) \mathrm{d}x_i}
\\
\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial t^2}\int_0^l{v\mathrm{d}x_i}-\int_0^l{\nabla ^2v\mathrm{d}x_i}&=\int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x},t \right) \mathrm{d}x_i}
\\
-\sum_{j=1}^n{\int_0^l{\partial _{j}^{2}v\mathrm{d}x_i}}&=\int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x},t \right) \mathrm{d}x_i}\,\,   \;\;(\text{with} \int_0^l{v\mathrm{d}x_i}=0)
\\
-\sum_{j\ne i}^n{\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x_{j}^{2}}\int_0^l{v\mathrm{d}x_i}}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}v\left( \boldsymbol{x},t \right) \mid_{x_i=0}^{x_i=l}&=\int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x},t \right) \mathrm{d}x_i}
\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}v\left( \boldsymbol{x},t \right) \mid _{x_i=0}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}v\left( \boldsymbol{x},t \right) \mid _{x_i=l}&=\int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x},t \right) \mathrm{d}x_i}\,\,\;\;(\text{with} \int_0^l{v\mathrm{d}x_i}=0)
\end{align}
$$

The 1-D form
The 1-D form, which means that $n=1$, is very simple when homogenizing. Just considering the transform
$$u(x, t)=v(x, t)+\frac{x^{2}}{2 l} \int_{0}^{l} q(x, t) \mathrm d x.$$

The step is shown below.
$$\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u\left( x,t \right) \mid _{x=0}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u\left( x,t \right) \mid _{x=l}
\\
=&\int_0^l{q\left( x,t \right) \mathrm{d}x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( \frac{x^2}{2l}\int_0^l{q\left( x,t \right) \mathrm{d}x} \right) \mid_{x=l}^{x=0}
\\
=&\int_0^l{q\left( x,t \right) \mathrm{d}x}\cdot \left( 1+\frac{x}{l} \right) \mid_{x=l}^{x=0}
\\
=&0
\end{align}$$


My attemption
Analogy
As $t$ is not used at all above, we omit it. Analogous to the 1-D method, I set
$$
u\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) =v\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) +\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{x_{i}^{2}}{2l}\int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mathrm{d}x_i}}.
$$
But it doesn't work, as
$$\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}u\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mid _{x_i=0}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}u\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mid _{x_i=l}
\\
=&\int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mathrm{d}x_i}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left( \sum_{j=1}^n{\frac{x_{j}^{2}}{2l}\int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mathrm{d}x_j}} \right) \mid_{x_i=l}^{x_i=0}
\\
=&\int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mathrm{d}x_i}+\sum_{j=1}^n{\left( \frac{x_j\mathrm{\mathrm{\delta}}_{ij}}{l}\int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mathrm{d}x_j}+\frac{x_{j}^{2}}{2l}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mathrm{d}x_j} \right)}\mid_{x_i=l}^{x_i=0}
\\
=&\sum_{j\ne i}^n{\frac{x_{j}^{2}}{2l}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x},t \right) \mathrm{d}x_j}}\mid_{x_i=l}^{x_i=0}
\end{align}$$
is $0$ only at $n=1$.
Combination
I think the transform is
$$
u\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) =v\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) +f\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) ,
$$
and the main point is to solve the $f\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right)$. After substituting it into the the boundary conditon, one can get
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}u\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mid _{x_i=0}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}u\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mid _{x_i=l}=\int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mathrm{d}x_i}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mid _{x_i=0}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mid _{x_i=l}
.$$
There are $n$ equations, and the right hand has to be $0$. So I think the $f\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right)$ must satisfy the form
$$
f\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) =\sum_{i=1}^n{g_i(\boldsymbol{x})\int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mathrm{d}x_i}}
$$
Only through this one can eliminate the $\int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mathrm{d}x_i}$. So let's calculate:
$$\begin{align}
&\int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mathrm{d}x_i}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\sum_j{g_j\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mathrm{d}x_j}}\mid _{x_i=l}^{x_i=0}
\\
=&\int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mathrm{d}x_i}+\sum_j{\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}g_j\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mathrm{d}x_j}+g_j\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mathrm{d}x_j} \right)}\mid _{x_i=l}^{x_i=0}
\end{align}.$$
This is so complicated.
2-D trial
Let us use the notation $\int_0^l{q\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mathrm{d}x_i}:= k\left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) \mid_{x_i=x_{i0}}^{}$, and consider the 2-D form:
$$
\begin{cases}
 k\left( x_{10},x_2 \right) +\left( \frac{\partial g_1\left( x_1,x_2 \right)}{\partial x_1}k\left( x_{10},x_2 \right) +\frac{\partial g_2\left( x_1,x_2 \right)}{\partial x_1}k\left( x_1,x_{20} \right) +g_2\left( x_1,x_2 \right) \frac{\partial k\left( x_1,x_{20} \right)}{\partial x_1} \right) \mid_{x_1=l}^{x_1=0}=0\\
 k\left( x_1,x_{20} \right) +\left( \frac{\partial g_1\left( x_1,x_2 \right)}{\partial x_2}k\left( x_{10},x_2 \right) +\frac{\partial g_2\left( x_1,x_2 \right)}{\partial x_2}k\left( x_1,x_{20} \right) +g_1\left( x_1,x_2 \right) \frac{\partial k\left( x_{10},x_2 \right)}{\partial x_2} \right) \mid_{x_2=l}^{x_2=0}=0\\
\end{cases}.
$$
The function $k$ is known, but how to decide $g_1$ and $g_2$? I have no idea. Mathematica tells me that Supplied equations are not differential equations of the given functions.. Could someone help me please? The code is below.
DSolve[{k[x10, x2] +
      ((# /. x1 -> 0) - (# /. x1 -> l)) &[
    D[g1[x1, x2], x1]  k[x10, x2] + D[g2[x1, x2], x1]  k[x1, x20] + 
     g2[x1, x2]  D[k[x1, x20], x1]] == 0,
  k[x1, x20] +
      ((# /. x2 -> 0) - (# /. x2 -> l)) &[
    D[g1[x1, x2], x2]  k[x10, x2] + D[g2[x1, x2], x2]  k[x1, x20] + 
     g1[x1, x2]  D[k[x10, x2], x2]] == 0}, {g1[x1, x2], 
  g2[x1, x2]}, {x1, x2}]

